# For rotating logs- Cronjob issue

Tags: linux, cron, authentication, pam, logrotate

Invoking `logrotate` every 15 mins.

`logrotate` will rotate only after size threshold crosses 1M

---

## Working machine

```
[root@machine1 output]# ls -l --block-size=1K
total 296
-rw------- 1 root root  55 Oct 15 10:46 all_devices.log
-rw------- 1 root root 122 Oct 15 10:00 all_devices.log-2018-10-15-1539612001.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 114 Oct 15 10:45 all_devices.log-2018-10-15-1539614701.gz
[root@machine1 output]# cat ../conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf 
/app/syslog-ng/custom/output/all_devices.log {
size 1M
copytruncate
dateext
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
rotate 365
sharedscripts
compress
postrotate
     /app/syslog-ng/sbin/syslog-ng-ctl reload
endscript
}
[root@machine1 output]# crontab -l
# 00 23 * * * /TSM/bkup 1>/dev/null 2>&1
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf 
[root@machine1 output]# cat /etc/system-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
[root@machine1 output]# 
[root@machine1 output]# cat /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status
logrotate state -- version 2
"/var/log/yum.log" 2018-5-29-10:0:0
"/var/log/sssd/sssd_nss.log" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/boot.log" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/up2date" 2018-5-29-10:0:0
"/var/log/sssd/sssd_pam.log" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/sssd/sssd_LDAPFG.log" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/sssd/sssd_sudo.log" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/wtmp" 2018-5-29-10:0:0
"/var/log/chrony/*.log" 2018-5-29-10:0:0
"/var/log/sssd/sssd.log" 2018-5-29-10:0:0
"/var/log/spooler" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/falcon-sensor.log" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/app/syslog-ng/custom/output/all_devices.log" 2018-10-15-10:45:1
"/var/log/btmp" 2018-10-1-3:28:2
"/var/log/rhsm/rhsmcertd.log" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/puppet/*log" 2018-5-29-10:0:0
"/var/log/maillog" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/secure" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/rhsm/rhsm.log" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/messages" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
"/var/log/sssd/ldap_child.log" 2018-5-29-10:0:0
"/var/log/cron" 2018-10-15-3:35:1
[root@machine1 output]#
```

---

## Problem machine

```
[root@machine2 output]# ls -l --block-size=1K
total 2492
-rw------- 1 root root 2485 Oct 15 10:47 all_devices.log
[root@machine2 output]# 
[root@machine2 output]# 
[root@machine2 output]# 
[root@machine2 output]# cat ../conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf 
/app/syslog-ng/custom/output/all_devices.log {
size 1M
copytruncate
dateext
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
rotate 365
sharedscripts
compress
postrotate
      /app/syslog-ng/sbin/syslog-ng-ctl reload
endscript
}
[root@machine2 output]# 
[root@machine2 output]# 
[root@machine2 output]# 
[root@machine2 output]# crontab -l
# 00 23 * * * /TSM/bkup 1>/dev/null 2>&1
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf 
[root@machine2 output]# 
[root@machine2 output]# 
[root@machine2 output]# 
[root@machine2 output]# cat /etc/system-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
[root@machine2 output]# 
[root@machine2 output]# cat /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status 
logrotate state -- version 2
"/var/log/yum.log" 2018-6-18-19:0:0
"/var/log/sssd/sssd_nss.log" 2018-7-1-3:18:1
"/var/log/boot.log" 2018-6-19-3:14:1
"/var/log/up2date" 2018-6-18-19:0:0
"/var/log/sssd/sssd_pam.log" 2018-6-24-3:14:1
"/var/log/sssd/sssd_LDAPFG.log" 2018-9-9-3:47:1
"/var/log/sssd/sssd_sudo.log" 2018-6-24-3:14:1
"/var/log/wtmp" 2018-6-18-19:0:0
"/var/log/chrony/*.log" 2018-6-18-19:0:0
"/var/log/sssd/sssd.log" 2018-6-18-19:0:0
"/var/log/spooler" 2018-9-9-3:47:1
"/app/syslog-ng/custom/output/all_devices.log" 2018-10-10-11:0:0
"/var/log/falcon-sensor.log" 2018-9-9-3:47:1
"/var/log/btmp" 2018-9-1-3:14:1
"/var/log/rhsm/rhsmcertd.log" 2018-9-9-3:47:1
"/var/log/puppet/*log" 2018-6-18-19:0:0
"/var/log/maillog" 2018-9-9-3:47:1
"/var/log/secure" 2018-9-9-3:47:1
"/var/log/rhsm/rhsm.log" 2018-9-9-3:47:1
"/var/log/messages" 2018-9-9-3:47:1
"/var/log/sssd/ldap_child.log" 2018-6-18-19:0:0
"/var/log/cron" 2018-9-9-3:47:1
[root@machine2 output]#
```

---

As per the above, my understanding is,  cronjob is not invoking `logrotate` in `machine2` every 15 mins.

Because `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status` on `machine2` says, `logrotate` is not invoked every 15 mins.

On problem machine, below is the observation in `/var/log/cron`:

```
Sep  9 20:00:01 machine2 crond[102124]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Sep  9 20:00:01 machine2 crond[102124]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Sep  9 20:01:01 machine2 crond[102303]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Sep  9 20:01:01 machine2 crond[102303]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Sep  9 20:10:01 machine2 crond[110162]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Sep  9 20:10:01 machine2 crond[110162]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
:
:
Oct  3 10:50:01 machine2 crond[387863]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 10:50:01 machine2 crond[387863]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 10:57:44 machine2 crond[1895]: (CRON) INFO (Shutting down)
Oct  3 10:57:44 machine2 crond[392146]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 56% if used.)
Oct  3 10:57:44 machine2 crond[392146]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Oct  3 10:57:44 machine2 crond[392146]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)
Oct  3 10:57:46 machine2 crond[392146]: (CRON) INFO (Shutting down)
Oct  3 10:57:46 machine2 crond[392159]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 96% if used.)
Oct  3 10:57:46 machine2 crond[392159]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Oct  3 10:57:46 machine2 crond[392159]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)
Oct  3 11:00:01 machine2 crond[397340]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:00:01 machine2 crond[397340]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:01:01 machine2 crond[397518]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:01:01 machine2 crond[397518]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:10:01 machine2 crond[402878]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:10:01 machine2 crond[402878]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:20:01 machine2 crond[407579]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:20:01 machine2 crond[407579]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:30:01 machine2 crond[412423]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:30:01 machine2 crond[412423]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
```

There are no logs beyond 03-Oct in `/var/log/cron`

FYI.... below cronjob entry was added on 12-Oct:

```
[root@machine2 output]# crontab -l
    # 00 23 * * * /TSM/bkup 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf
```

systemd status for `crond` process:

```
[root@machine2 log]# tail -5 /var/log/cron
Oct  3 11:10:01 machine2 crond[402878]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:20:01 machine2 crond[407579]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:20:01 machine2 crond[407579]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:30:01 machine2 crond[412423]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct  3 11:30:01 machine2 crond[412423]: (root) FAILED to authorize user with PAM (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
[root@machine2 log]#
[root@machine2 log]#
[root@machine2 log]#
[root@machine2 log]#
[root@machine2 log]# systemctl status crond
â— crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-10-03 10:57:46 EDT; 1 weeks 5 days ago
 Main PID: 392159 (crond)
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
           â””â”€392159 /usr/sbin/crond -n

Oct 15 11:10:01 machine2.abc.com crond[58065]: pam_unix(crond:account): expired password for user root (password aged)
Oct 15 11:10:01 machine2.abc.com crond[58065]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct 15 11:15:01 machine2.abc.com crond[58989]: pam_unix(crond:account): expired password for user root (password aged)
Oct 15 11:15:01 machine2.abc.com crond[58989]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct 15 11:20:01 machine2.abc.com crond[60067]: pam_unix(crond:account): expired password for user root (password aged)
Oct 15 11:20:01 machine2.abc.com crond[60067]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct 15 11:30:01 machine2.abc.com crond[62044]: pam_unix(crond:account): expired password for user root (password aged)
Oct 15 11:30:01 machine2.abc.com crond[62044]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
Oct 15 11:30:01 machine2.abc.com crond[62045]: pam_unix(crond:account): expired password for user root (password aged)
Oct 15 11:30:01 machine2.abc.com crond[62045]: (root) PAM ERROR (Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required)
[root@machine2 log]#
```

---

How to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Also: since you are running logrotate as root (presumably), is `/app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf` owned by root?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Query updated

Comment: It seems you have another problem. Why are the cron logs at 10-minute intervals when you have a 15-minute cron schedule?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Does `crond` process suppose start and stop every 15 minutes? Is this the reason for so many process id?

Comment: @JeffSchaller cronjob entry was added on 12-Oct.

Comment: @JeffSchaller `systemd` status show Oct-15 entry, but `/var/log/cron` does not.. as updated in query..

Comment: Is root's password expired? `chage -l root`

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes... am working on it.